# How can replace multiple strings on same line or not in same line with PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace, brackets

Need regex to replace all inside brackets with myReplace !important need keep spaces and lines as is!

```
$fileContent = <div class="panel-body">
    {toChangeOne}{toChangeTwo}
                            {  
                    toChangeTree
                    }
</div>

$change = preg_replace('NEEDED_REGEX', 'myReplace', $fileContent);
```

Comment: And what do you want to do now? I only know you want to replace something. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want to replace the actual braces, too?  Or leave the braces and replace the text?

Comment: yes replace braces too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so basically all you'd need to do is look for a set of curly braces and replace that, plus everything inside of it.

Something like this should work for you:

```
<?php

$fileContent = '<div class="panel-body">
    {toChangeOne}{toChangeTwo}
                            {  
                    toChangeTree
                    }
</div>';

$fileContent = preg_replace('~\{.*?\}~sm', 'myReplace', $fileContent);

print $fileContent;
```

Here's what that expression means `\{.*?\}`:

- `\{` - Looking for an opening curly brace `{`.  We need to escape it with a backslash `\` since curly braces have special meaning in regex.
- `.*?` - Match any character `.`, any number of times `*` until we hit the next part of our statement `?`.
- `\}` - The next part of our statement is a closing curly brace `}`.  Again, we need to escape it with a backslash `\`.

Here is a working demo:

http://ideone.com/Pi8OvI

Comment: Yes that is.. One last question! if i have {toChange {something} One} i want keep  {something} as is

Comment: Well that is more of a challenge.  You can do it a couple of ways, but it's going to be way more difficult.  First, you can make the expression greedy by removing the question mark.  `\{.*\}`, but that will match everything in your script from the first curly brace to the last curly brace.  If they're on separate lines, you can remove the `sm` flags at the end to make it not span multiple lines and that may work. Another method is to use `preg_replace_callback` to evaluate each match and check for the presence of an opening curly brace in the middle of your match. Skip it if it finds a match.

Comment: Can you make an preg_replace_callback?

Comment: Another option would be to run something like this multiple times: `\{[^{}]*\}`.  That would replace the innermost occurrences of the braces, but leave the outer ones.  So you'd need to run it twice.  As I mentioned earlier, it can be done, but the level of complexity rises quite a bit with something like this.

Comment: You should probably make that a new question because that's not something that I can put in the comments.

Comment: Oh, one more thing you can try - using recursion (which PHP supports) like this: `\{((?>[^{}]+)|(?R))*\}`.  Check out this link for an example: http://ideone.com/rmOEvv

Answer (score 1):

You could also approach your problem using an array of keys to change as below. This might be helpful when trying to replace multiple strings.

```
<?php

// array with keys that you'll be changing in your text
$toChange = array(
"{toChangeOne}" => "First Change",
"{toChangeTwo}" => "Second Change",
"{toChangeThree}" => "Third Change"
);


$fileContent = '<div class="panel-body">
    {toChangeOne}{toChangeTwo}
                            { 
                    toChangeThree
                    }
</div>';

// loop through all the keys you want to change
foreach($toChange as $key => $value){

    // prep regex
    // remove the openning and curly braces this 
    // way we can match anything that matches our 
    // keys even if there's a mixture of returns 
    // or empty spaces within the curly braces 
    $key_text = str_replace("{", "", $key);
    $key_text = str_replace("}", "", $key_text);

    // "\{"             - matches the character "{" literally
    // "(\s|\s+)?"      - matches any white space. In our case 
    //                    we might want it to be optional hense 
    //                    the "?"
    // "\}"             - matches the character "}" literally   
    $regex = '/\{(\s|\s+)?'.$key_text.'(\s|\s+)?\}/';

    $fileContent = preg_replace($regex, $value, $fileContent);
}

echo $fileContent;
```